# C return struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    char *name;
    Person *next_ptr;
}
```

Now I have a function that generates 2 people and returns pointer to the first struct:

```
Person *GetPerson(){
char[5] p1name = "John";
char[4] p2name = "Bob";

struct Person *p1;
struct Person *p2;

p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
strcpy(p2.name, p2name);
p2->age = 25;

p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
strcpy(p1.name, p1name);
p1->age = 20;
p1->next_ptr = p2;

return p1;
}
```

And the usage of the function to extract both Person.

```
struct Person *person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
person = GetPerson();
int person1age = person.age; // Get age
char person1name[4] = person.name; // Get name
int *person2_ptr = person.next_ptr; // Extract the person 2 pointer

struct Person *person2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
person2 = (*person2_ptr);
char person2name[4] = person2.name; // gets person 2 name
int person2age = person2; // get person 2 age
```

I hope I made clear what I am attempting to do. Can someone show me the correct way to implement this?

Comment: p1 is a `struct Person` that is on the stack. the function `GetPerson` is declared to return a Person * ( presumably Person is a typedef to struct Person ) which should be allocated on the heap and returned. reading on a little bit, you actually are mallocing p1 and p2, so adjust these to struct Person *. also post a complete program and state exactly whats not working and why

Comment: Declare char arrays with brackets after the name.  Also Make sure to leave room for the null terminator on your strings!  `char p1name[5] = "John"`

Comment: doesnt `char p1name[5]` ask for 6 chars because of 0 index?

Comment: No. It asks for 5 bytes.

Comment: You've not allocated space for the name strings.  You've not got a way to return the second structure pointer.

Comment: can you show me a way to do that?

Comment: I left you a detailed answer describing the issues. Unfortunately there are many. read the solution and if you have question comment

Comment: @amdixon `p1` points to malloc'd space

Comment: @M.M when comment was written, OP code had p1 as a struct Person. yes it is now correctly mallocd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there are a lot of mistakes in your code.

1.
In C, unlike C++, every time you want to make an instance of `struct Person`, you have to say `struct Person`, not `Person`

2.
In C, the way to declare a `char` array of size 5 is `char p1name[5];`  not `char[5] p1name;`

3. Inside the body of `GetPerson()` `p1` and `p2` are declared as pointers, that means `strcpy(p1.name,p1name);`  should actually be `strcpy(p1->name,p1name);`
   or even `strcpy((*p1).name,p1name);` if you prefer.

More serious problems:

4. You have to notice that when you allocate memory dynamically for an instance of `struct Person`, you do not automatically allocate memory for the `char * name;`; because of this calling `strcpy(p1->name,p1name);` will fail. You could keep the `char*` and allocate memory for it dynamically, but for the sake of simplicity I would recommend you just pick a `char` array of reasonably large size.
5. Remember that `GetPerson()` allocates memory for an instance of `struct Person`and returns a pointer.  Now inside your main function you have:

   ```
   struct Person *person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); //allocating memory in main
   person = GetPerson();  // you just leaked the memory you allocated in main
   ```

   You are allocating memory twice. This will not cause your program to crash, but will cause a "memory leak" which you need to avoid. You always want to `free()` dynamically allocated memory.

Put that together and you get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    int age;
    char name[256];
    struct Person *next_ptr;
};

struct Person * GetPerson(){
    char p1name[5] = "John";
    char p2name[4] = "Bob";

    struct Person *p1;
    struct Person *p2;

    p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    strcpy(p2->name, p2name);
    p2->age = 25;
    p2->next_ptr=NULL;

    p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    strcpy(p1->name, p1name);
    p1->age = 20;
    p1->next_ptr = p2;

    return p1;
}

int main()
{
    struct Person * tmp=GetPerson();

    printf(tmp->name); //prints John
    printf("\n");
    printf(tmp->next_ptr->name); //prints Bob
    printf("\n");
    free(tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that this is still not great code logically, but it does not have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Person p1;
```

Should be a pointer:

```
struct Person *p1;
```

And likewise for `p2`.

Then when you want to access fields in the struct, you cannot do this:

```
p2.age = 25;
```

Instead, you must use:

```
p2->age = 25;
```

Because `p2` is now a pointer rather than an instance.  The above is equivalent to:

```
(*p2).age = 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are not allocating space for the string that holds the person's name itself. So when you do

```
p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
strcpy(p2->name, p2name);
```

p2->name isn't really pointing anywhere of significance, and things will fail. You have 2 options here, one is to malloc both the structure and enough space for the name separately with 2 mallocs:

```
p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
p2->name = malloc(60); // deemed sufficient for name
strcpy(p2->name, p2name);
```

or alternatively, you declare name as an array in which case it will have its own space allocated by changing the structure definition to:

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    char name[60];
    Person *next_ptr;
}
```

in which case the original malloc will allocate space for name also. Either one should work. And whatever was said for p2 also applies to p1.